# Why am I getting this SQL/DB error?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to run a simple SQL statement with DB2 and am having a few problems.
I would like to have a single script in a txt/db2 file and have the engine process all of the commands

Here is the script:

```
CONNECT TO MYDB

CREATE TABLE PERSONS(
     PID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
     NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

TERMINATE
```

When I run a db2 -f /pathtofile I get:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "(" was found following "CREATE TABLE PERSONS".  
Expected tokens may include:  "END-OF-STATEMENT".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my script?
Also, why is it working without ";" terminators at the end of my statements?

Thank you,

Comment: What happens when you type your statements into the db2 command interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this will be of help,
http://www.uc.edu/R/r25/documentation/Version3.2/install_instructions.pdf:

> The scripts use a semi-colon (;) to terminate each SQL 
>   command. If you use the DB2 Command Line Processor, 
>   you should remember to use the “-t” flag.
>   ...
>   If you do not use the -t flag, you will get errors such as the
>   following upon running the db2ct32.sql script:
>   create table “ACCOUNTS” (
>   DB21034E The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
>   valid Command Line Processor command. During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0104N An unexpected token “(“ was found following “ate table “ACCOUNTS””.
>   Expected tokens may include: “END-OF-STATEMENT”. SQLSTATE=42601

So, I would add semicolons and invoke with -t switch whatever nonsense it stands for.
I looked into samples, they use something like

```
db2 -tf "pathtofile"
```

Also with

```
db2 -tvf "pathtofile"
```

you might get more diagnostics.
Don't push proprietary soft to the limits, they are not that wide.

Answer (score 2):

You have a comma after the name line

Change:

```
NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
```

to:

```
NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing this - however I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If I include semicolons and use the -t flag, I get:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "/" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  
Expected tokens may include:  "<values>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: looks like it treated your path or part of it as a script. 
Thats the only explanation for "/" that I have.

Answer (score 0):

I would insert a space or a line separator  between CREATE TABLE PERSONS and (
just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax without spaces works right on the command line,

`CREATE TABLE PERSONS (PID SMALLINT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)`

formatting a file with this and not the paragraph style worked for my assignment here - http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2016-17/F/3421/project/create/yrb-create.txt