# Convert Query to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2

In db2, can someone show me how to convert a query into a stored procedure, so that when the stored procedure is called it simply returns the same result set as the query would return.

For example, let say I have query like this:

```
select * from tablename
```

How would you turn this into a stored procedure that returns the same record set as is returned by just simply running the query directly?

Comment: What have you tried?  There's plenty of documentation that exists.

Comment: I've tried by looking at other people stored procedures, but just can't seem to create a template that succeeds in doing what I'm requesting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a procedure

Format is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <<SPmyProcedure>>
     AS
     BEGIN
      <---procedure definition here--->
         select * from tablename
     END
```

Then you can just call the procedure name and it will perform your query.

via

> exec SPmyProcedure

Comment: What do you put in the place of where you say "procedure definition here"? Sorry that need such spoon feeding on this.....

Comment: you can also perform some procedural codes on SQL. you can perform IF statements, create temp tables, and many more. You can have multiple selects inside a procedure, you can add rows, modify rows, delete rows, drop rows, etc. @LonnieBest Calling the Procedure name will call the definition of the sql procedure and in turn, execute those commands you have in the procedure.

Comment: I tried it, but keep failing, here's the [error](http://neartalk.com/ss/2017-03-20_002_526x390.png) I got.

Comment: @LonnieBest once you have created the procedure, to modify its content, you must use ALTER PROCEDURE instead of CREATE PROCEDURE (you may also drop the procedure and then create it again, up to you which you want). To execute the procedure just type 'exec sp_Lonnie_Test';  also not sure with the syntax for your fetch first 5 rows, you could try SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tlorder if it still returns an error

Comment: Apparently, there is something more fundamental that I'm missing. I got that [error](http://neartalk.com/ss/2017-03-20_002_526x390.png) upon trying to create the stored procedure. It is like I'm in the wrong environment for doing this stuff. I'm using [Dbeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) and maybe I need to learn how to do this from the command line or something.

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use table valued function like this?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [db].[fn_tablename]
(   

)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
  SELECT * from [db].tablename  
)
```

Comment: Interesting. I need to read up on when to use a stored procedure and when to use a table valued function.

Comment: I tried it, but got this [error](http://neartalk.com/ss/2017-03-20_001_549x441.png).

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568263/why-am-i-getting-this-sql-db-error